# Codeanywhere: How to remove white line across my editor

Tags: ide, editor, codeanywhere

I am fairly new to all of this, I have started using Codeanywhere and I can't figure out how to remove the vertical white line going across my screen, see picture below.

[image: Vertical White line]

It makes my editor space very narrow and it's very annoying.

I played around with most of the options under the View menu but I still can't figure out how to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

By default the ruler shouldn't be visible, but you can check for the following setting:

editor.rulers.

If set, it's an array with column numbers. If you want to turn it off, you can simply set an empty array like this:

"editor.rulers": []